# What is the temperature at the center of a gas turbine disc?

Tags: turbine, temperature

I realize that it varies with the temperature at the inlet of the turbine, materials, dimensions, etc. But I would be interested in knowing an orientative value. For example, for a turbine which has at the exit of the combustion chamber a temperature of 1300 K. For the first turbine stage, around what temperature will the shaft/ center of the disc be? We have no cooling system.